# Python mechanize: encode cause strange character

Tags: python, mechanize

Here is my code:

```
import re
import mechanize

br = mechanize.Browser()
br.open("http://www.douban.com/")
print br.title()
```

what I visit is a Chinese website, but the return title is strange character,

how can I fixed this problem?

Comment: Could you please give the strange character to us, by using repr(br.title())? Also please provide the original Chinese content.

Comment: @Sheng: the correct title should be `豆瓣`, but the strange character is `璞嗙摚`, which is not I want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because the charset issue. For example, in Python 3.X:

```
>>> print("豆瓣".encode("utf8").decode('gbk'))
璞嗙摚
```

In other words, thte content "豆瓣" from the serive is encoded in charset "utf8". But your client try to display it as charset "gbk". To solve this problem, you need to transfer the content between these two different charsets, such as br.title().encode('gbk').decode("utf8")

Comment: so this is just the display problem? what I get is still right, when I save it to database, the content is still in utf8?

Comment: @hh54188 Kind of, yes. In the memory, or in terms of the bytes, what you get is what you want. But your system has to choose a charset to interpret these bytes and print them out. The string is encoded as utf8 into bytes. If you use gbk charset to interpret these bytes, you will get the incorrect print_out_content.

Answer (score 1):

If you just do `br.title()` it will give you the unicode string of the special character.

`print` attempts to display the non-ASCII character by encoding the Unicode string.